# Foreach duplicating checkbox inputs form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, foreach

Instead of having 2 inputs with the full-time and the contractor box ticked, I have 4 inputs see below. How can I avoid the duplication of the inputs, and ends up with two inputs only that will have the boxes ticked for full-time and contractor?

Here is the code:

```
    <?php       
      $jobEmploymentType = "FULL_TIME,CONTRACTOR";
       $jobEmploymentTypeExplode = (explode(",",$jobEmploymentType));   
    //print_r($jobEmploymentTypeExplode);
           foreach ($jobEmploymentTypeExplode as $jobType) : ?>
                
   <span class="asterisk">*</span>  <label for="jobEmploymentType">Employment Type</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" id="fullTime" name="fullTime" value="FULL_TIME" <?= ($jobType == "FULL_TIME")? "checked":"";?>>
  <label for="fullTime"> FULL-TIME</label><br> 

  <input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" id="contractor" name="contractor" value="CONTRACTOR" <?= ($jobType == "CONTRACTOR")? "checked":"";?>>
  <label for="contractor"> CONTRACTOR</label><br>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

**Expecting result:**

[image]

Comment: You have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way that works for me using in_array:

PHP Code:

```
   $jobTypeExplode = (explode(",",$jobEmploymentType)); 
        
        if(in_array('FULL_TIME',$jobTypeExplode)) {$fulltime = 'FULL_TIME';} 
  
     if (in_array('CONTRACTOR',$jobTypeExplode)) {$contractor = 'CONTRACTOR';}
```

HTML code:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" id="fullTime" name="fullTime" value="FULL_TIME" <?= ($fulltime == "FULL_TIME")? "checked":"";?>>
  <label for="fullTime"> FULL-TIME</label><br> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" id="contractor" name="contractor" value="CONTRACTOR" <?= ($contractor == "CONTRACTOR")? "checked":"";?>>
  <label for="contractor"> CONTRACTOR</label><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

$jobEmploymentType = "FULL_TIME,CONTRACTOR";

Your problem is in the above line. When you give two values to the variable $jobEmploymentType the program is going to spit out the program twice.